# How to measure memory bandwidth for a particular python program executing on ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, memory-bandwidth

I'm training a simple neural network and wanted to track the memory bandwidth for that particular python job. Can anyone let me know if there are any tools in Linux, that would help to give the report on memory bandwidth vs time graph or any memory bandwidth report?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a cli to view it at a glance, or are you looking for a monitoring tool for automated perf tests. `ytop` is a really nice process manager that has a memory-usage-vs-time graph, but it's systemwide

Comment: I'm looking for automated tools which can measure the memory bandwidth for the python program. Like some command line tools like mprof (memory profiler) which has the capability to measure the memory bandwidth of a program.